# Redemption with Outlook Object Model

Tags: outlook-redemption

I need to rewrite my Outlook Addin app to make it stable, crashing Outlook periodically is not an option. If I use RDOSession, do I need to change the code that loop through MAPIFolder to RDOFolder, MailItem to RDOMail, Attachment to RDOAttachment? Can I keep use the OOM objects on second thread together with RDOSession? 
Can I mix OOM and RDO in the Addin app which run on another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the code on the secondary thread needs to switch to the RDO objects.

OOM cannot be used on a secondary thread. Outlook 2016 will raise an exception as soon as it detects access on any thread but the main.